# Youtube data transfer missing revenue data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been collecting data on different youtube channels using Youtube transfers to Big Query, recently I gained access to a new youtube channel as a content owner on the first of this month, however for this channel, there is no row for this channel in these tables : *p_content_owner_ad_revenue_summary_a1*, *p_content_owner_ad_revenue_raw_a1*, *p_content_owner_asset_ad_revenue_summary_a1*, *p_content_owner_asset_ad_revenue_raw_a1*,*p_content_owner_claim_ad_revenue_summary_a1*.

I have check the access to all of my channels, and I do get content owner data for the new channel except the revenue data however I have rows in the tables *p_content_owner_asset_estimated_revenue_a1*, *p_content_owner_estimated_revenue_a1*. It seems like I have access to the estimated revenue but not the calculated revenue.